# AWS: Broadcast notifications for multiple worker processes running on multiple instances

Tags: notifications, publish-subscribe, broadcast, amazon-sqs

I have multiple application instances inside of Amazon EC2, each running several worker processes. What I want is each worker process to be subscribed to some notification(e.g. configuration change). This notification should be basically broadcast message, so that once it is sent - *every* worker receives it.

I know SQS does not support messages broadcast. Looking through similar questions/threads I see the suggestions to use SNS instead of SQS. I'm not sure this will work for me due to the following reasons:

- application instances are part of autoscaling group so they can be dynamically added and removed. In this case I don't see any clear way to unsubscribe every worker(I have multiple workers per instance) once instance gets terminated, which means I'll end up with the mess of dead subscribers after some time.
- protocol to use for subscription is also not clear. HTTP endpoint looks like the only option, which means my every worker should run HTTP server on its own port. It also looks I should listen only on instance public IP, which adds one more layer of complexity and insecurity.

At the moment I have a solution based on third party - I'm using 0MQ pub/sub server. But I'm looking for some out-of-box solutions AWS provides.

Thanks,
Vovan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The out-of-the-box AWS solution that comes to mind would be to create one SNS topic, and then for each instance, when the instance boots up, it would create its own SQS queue and subscribe the queue to the SNS topic, so that [each individual queue gets a broadcast copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNS_Scenarios.html) of each message you publish to SNS.

You'd want unsubscribe and delete these queues on instance termination, which could be done with [lifecycle hooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/adding-lifecycle-hooks.html).

If you didn't want to use a server to manage the processing of the lifecycle hooks (which publish the launch or termination events to SNS or SQS) you could create an AWS API Gateway endpoint to fire an AWS Lambda function, then subscribe the API Gateway endpoint to the SNS topic using https, to handle the cleanup tasks in Lambda, with no server needed.

That's several services working together and may sound a little complicated, but would be very inexpensive and require little maintenance or attention.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old thread, but I'd like to share my experience with this.  Kinesis has a 5 reads/sec throttle.  So if you have 10 nodes polling for events in the stream 1/sec, you're going to be in a constant state of throttling.
Kinesis looks to be primarily for massive writes with just a few readers, which doesn't quite fit a broadcast to many nodes use-case.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution I've figured out is to use Amazon Kinesis.The implication here is that each subscriber has to maintain it's own checkpoint to receive only most recent notifications.

Comment: Has your Kinesis solution work for your intended purpose. I presume you want to register multiple listeners that listen to Kinesis Stream and you want to send single message to Kinesis stream and want each listener to act on it

Answer (score 0):

Redis is handy solution for broadcasting a message to all subscribers on a topic. It is convenient because it can be used as a docker container for rapid prototyping, but is also offered by AWS as a managed service for multi-node clusters.

Comment: Redis pub/sub certainly works but the drawbacks for using it in AWS is that you either have to stand up a relatively expensive ElasticCache cluster, and then maintain it with periodic version updates (= downtime), or run your own Redis service. Securing Redis access will also be in scope. If you already have Redis as part of the infra, then yes, you may as well use it as the pub/sub backbone